# HTTP ERROR 500 for my event observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am new to Magento and was trying tutorial's example, and my site got broken with HTTP ERROR 500 when i have added my events.xml under my module's etc folder

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
    <observer name="predispatch" instance="MyCompany\Test\Observer\ControlerPreDispatch" shared="false" />
</event>
```

along with my observer and here is the constructor

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,\Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag)
```

Here is apache error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  `Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to MyCompany\\Test\\Observer\\ControlerPreDispatch::__construct() must implement interface Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\RedirectInterface,` .....
```

any clue?

Comment: Can you post your full code lines of your Observer?

Comment: did you clear var/generation?

Comment: namespace MyCompany\Test\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class ControlerPreDispatch implements ObserverInterface
{

 protected $redirect;
 protected $_actionFlag;
 
 public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,\Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag) 
 {
 $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
 }

Comment: public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
  $request = $observer->getEvent()->getData('request');
  if ($request->getModuleName() != 'catalog' || $request->getControllerName() !='product') {
   $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
   $this->_actionFlag->set('',\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
   $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(),'catalog/product/view/id/1');
  }
 }

Comment: No i didn't delete var/generation ... why should i ?

Answer (score 0):

All needed was just to delete the var/generation and recompile di again 
"php magento setup:di:compile"

Answer (score 0):

After editing **__construct** function of any class you need to remove /var/generation directory.